# Is it correct to use .call() to call a function immediately?

Tags: javascript

-Is it a proper way to use .call() to call a function instantly after it's declaration instead of using the syntax with parens like:
Instead of using:

```
(function([params]){ 
    //Code goes here 
})(/*params*/);
```

Can we do this?:

```
(function(/*possible params*/){
    //Code goes here
}).call(/*scope, [params]*/);
```

I read in a blog or a page that using .call() can be used to invoke functions anonymously so I assume it is correct to do it.
But I'm not sure what way of the 2 is better. I see it could be easier to use the first method.

Also, could I use this instantly invoking functions to, inside a literal object or a function constructor, create a variable inside that object which value is calculated doing some kind of algorithms inside an instantly self esecuted function when creating the object?
I.E: the example is very stupidi example but...
Sorry for the stupid example, I could not think of something better:

```
function Person(name, sex){
    this.name = name;
    this.sex = sex;
    this.description = (function(){
        let desc = "";
        let gender = "";
        if (sex == "male"){
            gender = "male";
        }
        else if (sex == "female"){
            gender = "woman";
        }
        desc += "I am a "+gender+" and my name is "+name;
        return desc;
    })(name, sex);
}

var p1 = new Person("Alice", "female");
alert(p1.description);
```

I tested it and it works, so I assume more complex things could be done and having variables private. Am I right?
I would be thankful if you could resolve my doubts about this.

Comment: The reason to use `.call()` instead of merely calling the function is that you need `this` to be bound to a particular value. If you don't need that, then there's no reason to use `.call()` (but it won't hurt anything).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to use `.call` or `.apply` on an IIFE function if there is no use of the `this` context within it as that is what `call` does for you.

The only reason I can see the need for it is maybe in a callback function where you need to bind the context in order to use `this` appropriately in the callback.

Comment: You are very welcome  @Lorthas . If it helped you can accept an answer :-)